# How to make angular controller minification safe

Tags: angularjs

I'm changing my angular controllers to minification friendly but I am getting a error with my $resource calls. all of my factories look the same as the one i am posting. I have followed the tutorials online but it is not working out for me.

```
//'use strict';
  app.controller('documentCtrl', ['$scope', '$upload', '$filter', '$route',  '$sessionStorage','$sce', '$q', '$modal', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope',  function (
$scope, $upload, $filter, $route, $sessionStorage, $sce, $q, $modal, $http, $location, $rootScope) {


$scope.docTypes = Type.query(function () { });
$scope.selectType = function () {

    var id = $scope.typeId.TypeId
    $http.get('/api/apiType/' + id)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.TypeName = result.TypeName
            console.log($scope.TypeName);
        });
};//


$scope.docPipes = Pipe.query(function () { });

$scope.selectPipe = function () {
    var id = $scope.pipeId.PipeId
    $http.get('/api/apiPipe/' + id)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.PipeName = result.PipeName
            console.log($scope.PipeName);
        });
};//
```

Factory

```
'use strict'
 app.factory('Type',['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/apiType/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET', isArray: false // this method issues a PUT request
    }
}, {
    stripTrailingSlashes: false
 });
}]);
  app.factory('TypeUpdate',['$http', function ($http) {
  return {

    update: function (doc) {
        return $http.put('/api/apiType/' + doc.TypeId, doc);
    }
   };
 }]);
```

Error

> ReferenceError: Type is not defined

Update
Type is a $resource call defined in my factory.

Is this the way the controllers should be defined? The examples I found online did not include variables.

```
app.controller('documentCtrl', ['$scope', '$upload', '$filter', '$route', '$sessionStorage','$sce', '$q', '$modal', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', 'ngTableParams', 'notificationFactory', 'Type', 'Document', 'Plant', 'Pipe', 'Company',  'Location', function (
$scope, $upload, $filter, $route, $sessionStorage, $sce, $q, $modal, $http, $location, $rootScope, ngTableParams, notificationFactory, Type, Document, Plant, Pipe, Company, Location) {
```

Comment: $scope.docTypes = Type.query(function () { }); What is this Type? You don't seem to have mentioned this in your list of dependencies for the controller

Comment: I think you answered my question. I wasn't sure if i needed to include them. see update.

Comment: you have declared a factory called "Type". This needed to be listed in you controller dependencies

Comment: ok, put it in a answer so i can give you credit

Comment: You need to include *everything* you want to inject into your controller. Be that services, factories, constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a factory called "Type". This needs to be listed in your controller dependencies.